# Get data from SQL using DataBinding and GetTable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to write this "profile" page for a website. In this page, users have to make their own profile and let us know about their information (like their phone number, address, birthday, etc.)
But before this page, users have already made their accounts by entering some other basic information (like name, email address and password).
so, in this "profile" page, they can enter new info or edit them.
This is my code, but It has 5 errors all in one line for now, there's probably more. I put the errors between **s.
Can anyone help?

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Profile.aspx.cs" Inherits="OnlineShop.Profile" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <center>
                <h1>Your Profile</h1>
            </center>
            <h3>Your information:</h3>
            <section>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Your username:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Username" runat="server" placeholder="Public username"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>First Name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Firstname" runat="server" placeholder="First name"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last name:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Lastname" runat="server" placeholder="Last name"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Birth date:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Birthdate" runat="server" placeholder="exp; 2000.Dec.23" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Email:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" placeholder="Email" TextMode="Email"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Phone number:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Phone" runat="server" placeholder="Phone number" TextMode="Phone"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Country:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Country" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Address:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Address" runat="server" placeholder="Address"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>ZIP Code:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Zipcode" runat="server" placeholder="ZIP Code"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Last Educational Certificate:</td>
                        <td><asp:DropDownList ID="Educertificate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Major:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Major" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Educational Status:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Edustatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>University/Institute:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Unuversity" runat="server" placeholder="University/Institute"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Job Status:</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="Jobstatus" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Company:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Company" runat="server" placeholder="Company"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <h3>Password:</h3>
            <section>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>New password:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Newpass" runat="server" placeholder="New password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Confirm password:</td>
                        <td><asp:TextBox ID="Confirmpass" runat="server" placeholder="Confirm password" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="Changepass" runat="server" Text="Change password" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </section>
            <section>
                <asp:Button ID="Savechanges" runat="server" Text="Save changes" OnClick="Savechanges_Click" />
                <asp:Label ID="scsmsg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </section>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

the code behind:

```
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            var query1 = from ID in onLinecontent.LookupCovers
                         join ProImage in onLinecontent.Products
                         on 
            **var users = onLinecontent.GetTable<User>();
            Username.Text = (from p in users
                             select p.UserUserName).FirstOrDefault();**

            var usr = (from p in onLinecontent.Users
                       select p);
            Username.DataBind();
            
            var cntry = (from p in onLinecontent.LookupCountries
                         select p);
            Country.DataSource = cntry;
            Country.DataTextField = "Title";
            Country.DataValueField = "Code";
            Country.DataBind();

            var edu = (from p in onLinecontent.LookupEdus
                       select p);
            Educertificate.DataSource = edu;
            Educertificate.DataTextField = "Title";
            Educertificate.DataValueField = "Code";
            Educertificate.DataBind();

            var ests = (from p in onLinecontent.LookupStatusEdus
                        select p);
            Edustatus.DataSource = ests;
            Edustatus.DataTextField = "Title";
            Edustatus.DataValueField = "Code";
            Edustatus.DataBind();

            var jsts = (from p in onLinecontent.LookupStatusJobs
                        select p);
            Jobstatus.DataSource = jsts;
            Jobstatus.DataTextField = "Title";
            Jobstatus.DataValueField = "Code";
            Jobstatus.DataBind();

            var mjr = (from p in onLinecontent.LookupMajors
                       select p);
            Major.DataSource = mjr;
            Major.DataTextField = "Title";
            Major.DataValueField = "Code";
            Major.DataBind();

        }
    }

    protected string GetStatus(int theID)
    {
        // get the string you need, based on the ID
        string thestring = "Hello World" + theID.ToString();
        return thestring;
    }

    protected void Savechanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OnlineShopDCDataContext onlineshop = new OnlineShopDCDataContext();
        var users = onlineshop.GetTable<User>();
        User usrn = new User();

        usrn.UserID = DataBaseHelper.GetNextProductID();
        usrn.UserFirstName = Firstname.Text;
        usrn.UserLastName = Lastname.Text;
        usrn.UserUserName = Username.Text;
        usrn.UserEmail = Email.Text;
        usrn.UserPhoneNumber = Phone.Text;
        usrn.UserCountry = Country.Text;
        usrn.UserAddress = Address.Text;
        usrn.UserZIPCode = Zipcode.Text;
        usrn.UserLastCertificate = Educertificate.Text;
        usrn.UserMajor = Major.Text;
        usrn.UserEduStatus = Edustatus.Text;
        usrn.UserJobStatus = Jobstatus.Text;
        usrn.UserCompany = Company.Text;
        usrn.UserIntitute = Unuversity.Text;
        usrn.BirthDate = Birthdate.Text;
        
        users.Context.SubmitChanges();
        scsmsg.Text = "Your Information has been saved successfully.";
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```html
Table<User> users = onLinecontent.GetTable<User>();
Username.Text = (from p in users
                      select p.UserUserName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: No it's not! I didn't know how to continue. It was supposed to get the profile picture if there was any, using the picture's ID.

Comment: it not use, you have to make a note of it! , An incomplete statement will result in an error in the next sentence.

Comment: Noted! But how should I do what I wanted to? How should I get the data from SQL? Is it right?